# Number theoretic answer for set membership

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I want a number theoretic answer to the below question, taken from the section 1.3, question no. #13 from the book of 'Abstract Algebra' by 'Hillman, Peterson'.

Let a be in 1+4Z, and let b in 2+4Z

a. Is b-a always in 1+4Z? explain

b. Is b+a always in 1+4Z? explain

I am unable to prove by a number theoretic approach, although taking a few examples is possible for me to get an answer.

Comment: Not sure what a number theoretic answer might look like.  If $a=1+4n,b=2+4m$ then it is easy to see that $b-a=1 +4(n-m)$ and $b+a=3+4(n+m)$.

Comment: Do you know about $Z/4Z$ or more generally $Z/nZ$. Specifically, do you know, that the canonical map $Z \to Z/nZ$ is a ring homomorphism.
Both questions become trivial if you know these easy facts, which one might view as basic algebraic number theory.

Comment: @kesa Very nice, but for somebody like me (i.e., trying to venture into Abstract algebra, & Number theory at the same time), a link to understand your answer would benefit a lot.

Comment: @lulu I feel it is obvious from your answer that both 'b-a', & 'b+a' have the same parity.This adds further meaning to the question. May be, I am wrong; may be more details need be worked out to prove the parity issue.

Comment: You are right that both have the same parity (again from the viewpoint of abstract algebra, this lies in the fact that a+b and a-b coincide in Z/2)
The connection between these fields I wanted to make is not so deep if you are just learning the stuff. In my opinion it is always fruitful to view these basic NT questions in terms of commutative algebra; here, what I mean is translating them into questions about the rings of the form Z/nZ and using the fact that the quotient map is a ring hom. 
Then the confusing notation becomes clear aswell

Comment: @kesa It would be much more effective if it is shown in abstract algebra how a+b & a-b coincide in Z/2. I feel circularity of reasoning in your answer, as am unable to find any further axiom to reach to. Or even, a simpler way could solve the parity issue.

Comment: I just wanted to make the following point: All these questions can be answered by the fact that $Z/nZ$ is a ring in such a way that $Z \to Z/nZ$ is a ring homomorphism. Of course, proving this essentially does the same as the calculation you are doing in solving the exercise (thus the circularity you mention). However, this is a general procedure (taking quotient by an ideal), which solves all kinds of these questions at once, and you don't need these explicit calculations every time!

Comment: @kesa I would be highly thankful for your response, if some link is provided that easily (given my level) teach one to delve to understand the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an exercise intended to teach you how to use definitions in a mathematical proof.  Presumably the book defines the notation $1+4Z$ so that $a$ is in $1+4Z$ if and only $a=1+4m$ for some integer $m$, and likewise $b$ is in $2+4Z$ if and only if $b=2+4n$ for some integer $n$.  In that case $b-a=(2+4n)-(1+4m)=1+4(n-m)=1+4m'$ where $m'=n-m$ is an integer, which means that $b-a$ is in $1+4Z$. This takes case of part a.

For part b, we see that $b+a=(2+4n)+(1+4m)=3+4(n+m)$, which means $b+a$ is in 3+4Z.  It should be obvious that $1+4Z$ and $3+4Z$ are disjoint sets, but to prove it (by contradiction), note that $1+4m=3+4n$ implies $2=4(m-n)$, which implies $1=2(m-n)$, which implies $1$ is an even number.

Comment: But, seemingly the question should ask about both part (a) & (b) to be in the same set, i.e. 1 + 4$Z$. You have proved that part (b) has to be in a disjoint set of 3 + 4$Z$. I feel that you are correct, but it is obvious parts (a) & (b) difference is 2a. I cannot tell the significance in the question's context, but for a,b in $Z$, this means that parity must be the same.